# Spotlight won't find files on NAS drive using AFP or SMB

Tags: mac-osx

This used to work and I am unclear as to why it stopped, maybe after a system update, I don't know.

I have verified that indexing for the AFP volume is enabled.
I have verified that an index is created on my Mac in /private/var/db/Spotlight-V100/Volumes for my NAS drive.
I have verified that mds and mds_stores processes are running.

I have reindexed multiple times both as SMB and as AFP and neither one works.

Does anybody know what the permissions are "supposed" to be for the Spotlight indexes?

What are the next steps to take to get to the bottom of this?